# Can't specify Lambda alias or version for SNS subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I've set up an SNS subscription to start up a lambda function when it get's triggered and it's all working fine, but the issue is that I can't seem to specify a version or alias of the lambda to call. Here's a screenshot of my settings:

[image]

And I followed along [Using Amazon SNS for System-to-System Messaging with an AWS Lambda Function as a Subscriber - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda-as-subscriber.html) to get setup but in step 6 it talks about the "Version or Alias drop-down box", but I can't find that anywhere.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

So I figured out how to point the SNS to trigger a specific alias of a lambda function. In the Lambda function after you've connected up your SNS trigger you should see it in the trigger list in the designer in the lambda view as pictured below:

[image]

Hit the `X` on that to clear it. Next up switch to whatever alias you want to connect the SNS to. Then on the left hand list of triggers in the designer, select SNS. It should get added and tell you that configuration is required, as seen below:

[image]

Click on `Configuration required` and you will be brought to a `Configure triggers` view down the bottom. Then simply select the SNS topic you're interested in and click `Add` in the bottom right.

It's a bit of a round about way of getting it done, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with SQS, the same happens when you add a Lambda trigger to a queue; you can’t set the alias or version number. However, when you add the SQS queue as a source for the Lambda to trigger on, from the Lambda console, it does work. You first select the alias or version in Lambda and after that add the source trigger. I expect the same is true for SNS.

The console is a bit asymmetrical in this sense. Hope this will be fixed soon.